# Infinite loop with '\.I' in babelbib in a Spanish document

Tags: bibtex, babel, spanish

I came across the following problem with TeXlive 2019 (Fedora's version 32): The minimal file (to print out and check a bibliography) hangs on the unusual author's first name here.

```
\documentclass[english, spanish]{article}

\listfiles

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{babplain-fl}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{referencias}
\end{document}
```

The bibliography database (very mangled entry) is:

```
@Article{2020SciPy-NMeth,
  language =     {english},
  author =       {Polat, {\.I}lhan},
  title =        {{SciPy} 1.0: {F}undamental Algorithms for Scientific
                                Computing in {P}ython},
  journal =      {Nature Methods},
  year =         2020,
  volume =       17,
  pages =        {261--272},
  adsurl =       {https://rdcu.be/b08Wh},
  doi =          {10.1038/s41592-019-0686-2}
}
```

It hangs on the name (some sort of infinite loop on the `{\.I}`).

Strangely, the same setup works fine with the full text using the memoir class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`babel-spanish` redefines `\.` in order to allow you to use `\...` as a convenient replacement for `\dots`. This happens in `\textspanish`, a more or less internal `babel-spanish` macro that is added to `\extrasspanish`. `\textspanish` saves `\.` before it does its redefinitions.

The issue you are facing arises if for some reason `\textspanish` gets called twice: The first call redefines `\.` and the second call stores that redefinition in the saved definition of `\.`. This results in an infinite loop when we try to use `\.`.

The problem is that `babelbib`'s language switching command `\btxselectlanguage` does

```
\csname extras#1\endcsname
\selectlanguage{#1}%
```

which means that it executes `extras<language>` twice (once explicitly and once via `\selectlanguage`). So for Spanish, `\textspanish` is executed twice.

You could load `babel` with the `babel-spanish` option `es-sloppy`, which would disable the redefinition of `\.`, but that would also disable a lot of other `babel-spanish` features.

It seems more logical, however, to redefine `\btxselectlanguage` to stop it from calling the language extras separately. The call to `\csname extras#1\endcsname` is redundant and can be removed (thanks to [Javier Bezos](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5735/javier-bezos) who points out [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544112/hang-with-pdflatex-bibtex/544127?noredirect=1#comment1374389_544127) that it *should* be removed, since it is not really supported to execute `\extras<language>` manually outside of the proper context).

```
\documentclass[english, spanish]{article}

\listfiles
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\renewcommand\btxselectlanguage[1]{%
  \bbbbifundefined{bibs#1}{%
    \bbbbifundefined{date#1}{%
      \PackageError{babelbib}{Language #1 in bibliography not loaded
        by babel}{%
        The language #1 hasn't been loaded by babel.
        Add it to the\MessageBreak
        options of the \string\usepackage{babel} command or to the
        global options.}%
    }{%
      \ifbbbbfixlanguage
        \PackageWarning{babelbib}{Language #1 in bibliography
          unknown\MessageBreak
          by babelbib. Hyphenation will be\MessageBreak
          incorrect}%
      \else
        \PackageError{babelbib}{Language #1 in bibliography unknown by
          babelbib}{%
          There are no definitions for #1 available in the
          current\MessageBreak
          version of babelbib. Please contact harald.harders@gmx.de.}%
      \fi
    }%
  }{%
    \selectlanguage{#1}%
  }%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{2020SciPy-NMeth,
  language = {english},
  author   = {Polat, {\.I}lhan},
  title    = {{SciPy} 1.0: {F}undamental Algorithms for Scientific
              Computing in {P}ython},
  journal  = {Nature Methods},
  year     = 2020,
  volume   = 17,
  pages    = {261-272},
  adsurl   = {https://rdcu.be/b08Wh},
  doi      = {10.1038/s41592-019-0686-2},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{babplain-fl}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: İlhan Polat: SciPy 1.0: Fundamental algorithms for scientific computing in Python. Nature Methods, 17:261–272, 2020.]

Comment: Executing `\extras...` out of the proper context (inside a `babel` language selector) is not a good idea, and can lead to infinite loops like this.

Comment: That does fix it for me. I just wonder why it didn't break the same way in the main (memoir) document. Oh, well.

Comment: @vonbrand Yeah, I read your aside about `memoir` and was wondering myself. But the MWE still reproduced the issue when I switched to `memoir`, so I didn't do any more digging.

Comment: @JavierBezos Thank you very much for the comment. I added it to the answer to make it clear that removing `\csname extras#1\endcsname` from `\btxselectlanguage` is not just a work-around, but actually the right think to do anyway.